# Map disappears when setCenter in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have a problem centering the map in OpenLayers 3:

When i click the button to center the map, the map dissapears, this only happen with the version 3.19.1 of openlayers. The same code with vesion 3.17.1 works well.

Why is happenning this?

[Fiddle 3.19.1 (Map dissapear)](https://jsfiddle.net/hatux7/wo9uvw16/)

[Fiddle 3.17.1 (Works)](https://jsfiddle.net/hatux7/yzdzL41w/)

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the coordinates... take a look at this fiddle where I've put the map in 4326 and transform your 3857 coordinates in 4326: https://jsfiddle.net/wo9uvw16/2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your example works perfect, i made some changes to the code to work with 3857 but stills don't work, is really weird: [https://jsfiddle.net/wo9uvw16/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/wo9uvw16/3/)

Comment: Both work for me. It is likely to be some kind of system specific bug. Do you see an errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: The console is not reporting any error, when you click the center button the map dissapears, but the controls of the zoom and atributtions still there, is weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem of the map dissapear.

When you use the javascript function ***split*** and pass to the function a **string**, it creates an array of **strings**.

Example:

```
var lonlat= "-103,24";
var lonlat_array = lonlat.split(",");
// Create: ["-103", "24"]
```

So, the ***setCenter*** function of OpenLayers 3 expects an array of numbers, when receive an array of strings the map dissapears.

To fix this issue i need to create an array of **numbers** this way:

```
var lonlat= "-103,24";
var lonlat_array = lonlat.split(",").map(Number);
// Create: [-103, 24]
```

Then when i use the setCenter it works perfect:

https://jsfiddle.net/wo9uvw16/4/

In the fiddle i send to the console both cases to see the diferences, thanks all of you for the help!

Comment: You just saved my life